# Proxy voip server to use ISP's VOIP service outside

Tags: proxy, voip, voice

I figured out how to get my ISP's voip credentials from my router. I used them on an iPhone voip app and it works but if I am not using isp's network it doesn't work.

So I am trying to run a proxy voip server to use my voip service outside of the my isp's network (on another country or cellular data).

What is the easiest solution to do that?

Comment: What router is it?  Some will let you use voip (rather than dect) handsets, which means you could connect your phone to the router, and forward calls that way.

Comment: @Paul , It's a cheap huawei home router, I checked that feature but it doesn't support it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way? And how did you get the ISP's credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Set up your home connection as a VPN then you will always be on your isp when you connect to the VPN.

Comment: If you need help or want me to point you in the right direction to set one up let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the point, but I want to use a voip server or similar approach to handle that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also have been trying a lot to realize that.
I tried FreePBX, siproxd and coturn.
FreePBX succeeded in realizing.

I read this article.

- https://www.sabo-net.info/2014/03/19/raspberry-pi%e3%81%a7%e3%81%b2%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e9%9b%bb%e8%a9%b1%e3%82%92%e6%8c%81%e3%81%a1%e6%ad%a9%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e2%91%a0/ (Japanese only...)

( But I don't like this method, because I have to prepare one machine dedicated to install FreePBX distro on.
If you want to use another distro, you have to setup Asterisk, FreePBX and so on by yourself. )